# Optimization of a Brute Force algorithm implemented in Batch script

Tags: algorithm, batch-file, brute-force

The purpose of this Batch script is to implement a simple Brute Force algorithm in order to generate all the possible 10 alphanumeric character long strings with no repetition between a character and its next one.

```
set alphanumerics=a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

for %%l in (%alphanumerics%) do (
    for %%m in (%alphanumerics%) do (
        for %%n in (%alphanumerics%) do (
            for %%o in (%alphanumerics%) do (
                for %%p in (%alphanumerics%) do (
                    for %%q in (%alphanumerics%) do (
                        for %%r in (%alphanumerics%) do (
                            for %%s in (%alphanumerics%) do (
                                for %%t in (%alphanumerics%) do (
                                    for %%u in (%alphanumerics%) do (

if %%u NEQ %%t (
    if %%t NEQ %%s (
        if %%s NEQ %%r (
            if %%r NEQ %%q (
                if %%q NEQ %%p (
                    if %%p NEQ %%o (
                        if %%o NEQ %%n (
                            if %%n NEQ %%m (
                                if %%m NEQ %%l (
                                    echo %%l%%m%%n%%o%%p%%q%%r%%s%%t%%u >> output.txt
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The main issue of this script is that the necessary time amount in order to accomplish the task is still really huge because thousands of invalid combinations are anyway computed by the `for` blocks despite the various `if` branches are filtering the final output. Due to this, I would really like to improve the whole script, using all the computational power in the best way without wasting it. I was thinking about a distribution of the entire algorithm between parallel processes. Or else, a power of 2 based string generator: in a first step, the script could generate and then store all the possible couples of characters.

```
for %%x in (%alphanumerics%) do (
    for %%y in (%alphanumerics%) do (
        if %%y NEQ %%x (
            echo.%%x%%y >> output.txt
        )
    )
)
```

Afterward, in a second step, it could use the previous generated couples to match them yielding four character long strings; then, eight character long, etc.

```
for /f %%v in (output.txt) do (
    set firstvar=%%v
    set firstchar=!firstvar:~1!
    ;First character of the listed couples

    for /f "skip=1" %%w in (output.txt) do (
        set secondvar=%%w
        set secondchar=!secondvar:~0,1!
        ;Last character of the listed couples

        if !secondchar! NEQ !firstchar! (
            echo.!firstvar!!secondvar! >> output_2.txt
        )
    )   
)
```

In conclusion, how I could improve this algorithm in order to spare time?

Comment: For starters, don't use a batch script...

Comment: I know that Batch is not definitely a good language for this kind of task, but I currently have no knowledge about low level programming languages: I have just started to study Python but I am still a newbie with it. Furthermore, the idea to write a Brute Force algorithm with Batch is also due to its ideal utilization, that is to test the possibilities to force a BitLocker encryption through the Command Prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution below is *much faster* than yours, and perhaps this is the fastest way to do it in Batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "alphanumerics=a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,X,Y,Z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"

(for %%a in (%alphanumerics%) do (
   for %%b in (%alphanumerics%) do if %%a neq %%b (
      for %%c in (%alphanumerics%) do if %%b neq %%c (
         for %%d in (%alphanumerics%) do if %%c neq %%d (
            for %%e in (%alphanumerics%) do if %%d neq %%e (
               for %%f in (%alphanumerics%) do if %%e neq %%f (
                  for %%g in (%alphanumerics%) do if %%f neq %%g (
                     for %%h in (%alphanumerics%) do if %%g neq %%h (
                        for %%i in (%alphanumerics%) do if %%h neq %%i (
                           for %%j in (%alphanumerics%) do if %%i neq %%j (
                              echo %%a%%b%%c%%d%%e%%f%%g%%h%%i%%j
                           )
                        )
                     )
                  )
               )
            )
         )
      )
   )
)) > output.txt
```

Comment: I agree, the script is 2 times *much faster* :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Aacini. Your solution is fantastic because the `if` statements, in this case, manage the `for` loops sub-routine instead of simply filtering their output. I'm going to test it soon.

Comment: It is too bad that string substitution is not case sensitive!

Comment: @Paul _I agree, the script is 2 times much faster :)_  Then it only needs 8000 years, thats geat (based on the calculation of MC ND)! There might be a cause why long passwords are called strong.

Comment: @jeb: You should see this point from the good side: this script _saves 8000 years of processing time!!!_   **`;)`**

Answer (score 4):

```
26 lowercase + 26 uppercase + 10 digits = 62 characters
```

If there are 61 characters for each position (neighbor limitation) except for the first one that is not limited by the previous character, then you will have to generate

```
(61^9)*62 = 725037057755716742  combinations.
```

Generating 1000000 combinations per second you will need 22991 years to generate the full list and will require, with 10 characters and CRLF terminator after each value, 7728 PB of storage.

But ...

**NOTE 1**
 Script edited. As JosefZ pointed the original code failed because the string substitution in batch files is case insensitive (and I forgot it). The code has been changed to face the problem including a *filler* to be able to discriminate lower and upper characters, but not including it in the output. Anyway, the original wrong code can be found at the end of the answer.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "alphanumerics=,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z"
    set "alphanumerics=%alphanumerics%,!_!A,!_!B,!_!C,!_!D,!_!E,!_!F,!_!G,!_!H,!_!I,!_!J,!_!K,!_!L,!_!M,!_!N,!_!O,!_!P,!_!Q,!_!R,!_!S,!_!T,!_!U,!_!V,!_!W,!_!X,!_!Y,!_!Z"
    set "alphanumerics=%alphanumerics%,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
    set "_="

    rem Just for testing : 4*(3^9) = 78732 combinations
    set "alphanumerics=,a,b,!_!A,!_!B"

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for %%a in (!alphanumerics!
    ) do for %%b in (!alphanumerics:^,%%a^=!
    ) do for %%c in (!alphanumerics:^,%%b^=!
    ) do for %%d in (!alphanumerics:^,%%c^=!
    ) do for %%e in (!alphanumerics:^,%%d^=!
    ) do for %%f in (!alphanumerics:^,%%e^=!
    ) do for %%g in (!alphanumerics:^,%%f^=!
    ) do for %%h in (!alphanumerics:^,%%g^=!
    ) do for %%i in (!alphanumerics:^,%%h^=!
    ) do for %%j in (!alphanumerics:^,%%i^=!
    ) do echo(%%a%%b%%c%%d%%e%%f%%g%%h%%i%%j
```

When the code is executed, the `!_!` will be included inside the `for` replaceable parameters, but as the variable `_` is empty, it will not be included in the ouput of the `echo` command, replaced with the empty string in the delayed expansion parser phase.

---

This is the original (and wrong) code in the answer. Does not properly handle the upper/lower case string substitutions.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Changed to include a starting comma
    set "alphanumerics=,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,X,Y,Z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"

    for %%a in (%alphanumerics%
    ) do for %%b in (!alphanumerics:^,%%a^=!
    ) do for %%c in (!alphanumerics:^,%%b^=!
    ) do for %%d in (!alphanumerics:^,%%c^=!
    ) do for %%e in (!alphanumerics:^,%%d^=!
    ) do for %%f in (!alphanumerics:^,%%e^=!
    ) do for %%g in (!alphanumerics:^,%%f^=!
    ) do for %%h in (!alphanumerics:^,%%g^=!
    ) do for %%i in (!alphanumerics:^,%%h^=!
    ) do for %%j in (!alphanumerics:^,%%i^=!
    ) do echo %%a%%b%%c%%d%%e%%f%%g%%h%%i%%j
```

**NOTE 2**
 After writing it I have seen this is the same approach in the [JosefZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33512850/2861476) but as no variables are stored in the process it should be slightly faster.

Comment: Sorry, our approach is wrong as variable edit/replace is case insensitive. `%alphanumerics:a,=%` and `%alphanumerics:A,=%` are the same string. However, +1 for time calculation:) I go to calculate `Tebibyte` needs (independently on your answer)...

Comment: @JosefZ, Of course you are right, thank you. I forgot it `:,(`. But I like the approach, so, I changed it a bit to take avantage of delayed expansion parser to make it work.

Comment: The total amount of characters used in this algorithm is actually 62 because the Latin alphabet includes 26 characters.

Comment: @rudicangiotti, The missing lowercase `v` in the original question fooled me. Corrected, thank you

Comment: @MCND, yes, I realized it yesterday in the Batch file but I didn't remember to fix it also here in my question. Thank you too.

Answer (score 1):

You could exclude possible neighbour matches in advance as follows. Note that password seed in `alphanumerics` variable is cut and output is narrowed only to each ten-thousandth word merely for demonstration purposes.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "alphanumerics=a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,X,Y,Z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"
set "alphanumerics=a,b,c,d,e,A,B,C,D,E,0,1,2,3,4,5,"
set "alphanumerics=a,b,c,A,B,C,0,1,2,"
set "alphanumerics=a,b,A,B,0,1,"
set /A "_counter=0"
rem > output.txt (
for %%l in (%alphanumerics%) do (
    set "al=!alphanumerics:%%l,=!"
    for %%m in (!al!) do (
        set "am=!alphanumerics:%%m,=!"
        for %%n in (!am!) do (
            set "an=!alphanumerics:%%n,=!"
            for %%o in (!an!) do (
                set "ao=!alphanumerics:%%o,=!"
                for %%p in (!ao!) do (
                    set "ap=!alphanumerics:%%p,=!"
                    for %%q in (!ap!) do (
                        set "aq=!alphanumerics:%%q,=!"
                        for %%r in (!aq!) do (
                            set "ar=!alphanumerics:%%r,=!"
                            for %%s in (!ar!) do (
                                set "as=!alphanumerics:%%s,=!"
                                for %%t in (!as!) do (
                                    set "at=!alphanumerics:%%t,=!"
                                    for %%u in (!at!) do (

          rem echo %%l%%m%%n%%o%%p%%q%%r%%s%%t%%u
          set /A "_counter+=1"
          set /A "_inter=_counter %% 100000"
          if !_inter! EQU 0 echo %%l%%m%%n%%o%%p%%q%%r%%s%%t%%u !_counter!

                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
echo %_counter%
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

However, I'm afraid we do not have enough time (and disk space as well) to accomplish your task as iteration count grows exponentially or even faster!

There is `3479922` possible *passwords* (found in few minutes) with `set "alphanumerics=a,b,A,B,0,1,"`. To review growing time (and space), here is an extract of results achieved with `set "alphanumerics=a,b,c,A,B,C,0,1,2,"` (only three characters `c,C,2,` more in the password seed): still with leading `a` after more than **ten million iterations**...

```
acbcB2A21A 9600000
acbAcA2ABc 9700000
acbA121A1A 9800000
acbCB1aBCA 9900000
acb0bcAcba 10000000
acb01abCA1 10100000
acb1c0AcbA 10200000
acb12cABC2 10300000
acb2BacB2b 10400000
acAba0Bc02 10500000
^CacAbAB1bCb 10536175
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```